# Asus Transformer 4.1.1 Email Widget shows "Waiting for sync" forever

Tags: sync, 4.1-jelly-bean, app-widgets, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I have the Asus Transformer running Android 4.1.1.  I'm trying to use the email widget to check my mail.  When I enter in my account information, I get a screen that looks like this:

[image: Waiting For Sync]

All my settings work in any other mail client, but I'd obviously prefer to use this one.  Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Is automatic sync enabled in settings->your gmail account?

Comment: Auto sync is currently off.  Is this an issue?

Comment: Yes. The issue you are seeing is because the widget isn't syncing - it is waiting for it to sync, but can't because you have disabled it :)

Comment: Well its not gmail im trying to sync it with, but I'll try to enable autosync with the client I am using

Comment: If it is an email account, that email account should be listed in the same place as the Google.

Comment: Yeah I don't think that was the problem